# TinyMCE image upload. Restrict file types

Tags: c#, tinymce, tinymce-4

I would like the TinyMCE file picker to only allow users to select .png and .jpg file types.  Here is my init:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#txtMessage',
    plugins: [
      'advlist lists link image charmap print preview hr',//anchor pagebreak autolink
      'searchreplace wordcount fullscreen',  //visualchars  visualblocks code
      'insertdatetime save table contextmenu directionality',//media nonbreaking
      'emoticons paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools table' 
    ],
    toolbar1: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
    toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | codesample | table',
    image_advtab: true,
    relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host: false,
    convert_urls: true,
    force_br_newlines: false,
    force_p_newlines: false,
    forced_root_block: 'p',
    encoding: "UTF-8",
    automatic_uploads: true,
    images_upload_url: '@Url.Action("Upload", "Home", this.Request.Url.Scheme)',
    file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

        input.onchange = function () {
            var file = this.files[0];
            var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
            var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
            var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file);
            blobCache.add(blobInfo);                
            cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
        };
        input.click();
    }
});
```

In the `file_picker_callback` i have tried:

```
file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*.png, image/*.jpg');
```

This does not work as all file types are available for selection.  Is there a way to restrict the file picker to only allow .png and .jpg files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accept attribute allows you to be more specific than `image/*` but I think your formatting is off.  In an actual image tag you would do this:

```
<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />
```

So try something like:

```
input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/jpg, image/gif');
```

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows this in action:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/ROgaab

I did not hook up the file picker to anything so once you pick the file it won't actually do anything but setting that `input.setAttribute()` as I showed above limits me to picking just those two file types.

Comment: This kind of works.  It defaults to All Files(*) though.  Followed by All Supported Types (*.jpg, *.png).  I would prefer not to have the all files option be the default

Comment: @user2370664 please see the fiddle I created - with the code I suggested I am only allowed to pick jpg and gif files.  Do you get something different?